# Looping with while and foreach in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I cannot seem to get foreach to work. Maybe I do not understand it correctly.

Here is my code:

```
$statement = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY name ASC";
$query = mysql_query($statement)

...
...

$cals = array("sports","general","other","clubs");

foreach ($cals as $value)
{
/*  echo "<h3>".$value."</h3>"; 
*/  echo "<table width='100%'>";
while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        if ($array['calendar'] == $value)
        {?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $array['name']; ?></td>
  <td><a onclick="update_form('<?php echo $array['name']; ?>', '<?php echo $array['calendar']; ?>')" href="#">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
<?php }
    }
    echo "</table><br />Value: $value";
}
```

The goal of this is to have the foreach change the if statement. I had planned for the if statement to say: `if ($array['calendar'] == "sports")` the first time, `if ($array['calendar'] == "general")` the second time, and so on. However, it shows all of the tables (in the source code), but no table rows are created after the first for each array value. For example, I correctly see the sports table, but I do not see any table rows for general, other, or clubs. There are records in that database that should appear in each of those. Could it be a problem with the while and if statements? If I manually set the $value in the if statement to one of the values in the array, it shows the correct records.

What am I missing?

Sample Data:

in the MySQL database -

categories table.
fields:

- id
- name
- num_events
- calendar
- calendar_url

All of these fields except the calendar field has dummy data in it.

Currently, I have 5 records in there. Each one has a different calendar value. One is sports, one is clubs, and one is general. Depending on what value I place first in the array, it only shows that one table, of all of the values with whatever the first value in the array is.

Here is the source code from the resulting page:

```
<table width='100%'><tr>
  <td>test4</td>
  <td><a onclick="update_form('test4', 'sports')" href="#">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>test5</td>

  <td><a onclick="update_form('test5', 'sports')" href="#">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
</table><br />Value: sports<table width='100%'></table><br />Value: general<table width='100%'></table><br />Value: other<table width='100%'></table><br />Value: clubs
```

Comment: It would really help to see a sample set of data.  This looks generally correct (though I'm not sure what the `next()` call is all about).

Comment: I got rid of that. I was just trying things..lol...A sample of data...such as what is in the database? I'll see if I can get something up.

Comment: Alright, I wasnt sure on how to provide some sample data, but I added some more info.

Comment: `One is sports, one is clubs, and one is general.` - it's 3 values. But you have said there is 5. That's your main problem

Comment: @ Col. Shrapnel -well, I couldn't get anything past the first foreach array value, so I did figured it made that much of an impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just a point of style.  You might consider renaming your variable `$query` to something like `$results`.  It's holding the result of a query, not a query itself.

The problem is that you're not resetting `$results`.  After the first table, you've iterated all the way through the array.  When you get to the end, and there are no more rows to iterate over, `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns false.

So try this:

```
foreach ($cals as $value)
{
    while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        if ($array['calendar'] == $value)
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array['name']; ?></td>
                <td><a onclick="update_form('<?php echo $array['name']; ?>', '<?php echo $array['calendar']; ?>')" href="#">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
    echo "</table><br />Value: $value";
    mysql_data_seek($query,0); // <=== Set the resultsets internal pointer back to zero (the first record).
}
```

The important bit is the `mysql_data_seek()` on the second to last line.

You could also stick that `mysql_data_seek()` right before the `while()` line, if you prefer.  You just need to make sure that for each iteration of the foreach loop, the array pointer is reset before you hit `while()`.

**EDIT**: s/reset/mysql_data_seek/

Comment: You've got that part right that says that you'll end up exhausting records before iterating over all array items, but `reset($query);` wont help.

Comment: @Salman A - of course you're correct.  $query is a resultset, not an array.  Answer updated.

Comment: This did it. thanks a ton. I'm looking into some of the other methods that were posted here as well.

Answer (score 2):

As jcubic and timdev pointed out, there are a couple problems with the code as written.  However, the algorithm you're trying to use is very inefficient because it loops over the entire result set for every calendar type.  Instead, you can use a multi-column sort in SQL to do it in one pass:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY calendar, name";
$results = mysql_query($results)
...
...
$last_cal = '';
while ($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  if (!$last_cal) {
    echo '<table>';
  }
  else if ($array['calendar'] != $last_cal) {
    echo '</table>';
    echo '<table>';
  }
  ?>
   ....HTML for table row...
  <?php
  $last_cal = $array['calendar'];
}
```

Comment: Actually, nowadays we are always use 2 loops - one to get data and one to output. Very handy.

Comment: Having trouble parsing that comment.  What's handy about having 2 loops when 1 will do? And why do you need a loop to get the data? The db fetch is just a few statements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead...

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` return array indexed by integer if you want asoc array change

```
while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

to this

```
while ($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
```

Comment: "mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both [by default]": http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array